# Pass a string from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have an activity, and I need to pass a Textview called primary_phone_to_call to another activity. 
Activity one is below.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
            intent.putExtra("MyData", "primary_phone_to_call");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_GET_CONTACT);
```

Activity 2 is here

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
String stredittext = bundle.getString("MyData");
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(stredittext, "id", getPackageName());
TextView text_id = (TextView) findViewById(resId);
```

I've also tried this for activity 2

```
String stredittext = data.getString("MyData");
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(stredittext, "id", getPackageName());
        TextView text_id = (TextView) findViewById(resId);
```

Both are giving me a null result.  I can hardcode stredittext to primary_phone_to_call, and it works just fine.  Any suggestions?

Comment: your intent successfully starts the second activity?

Comment: If you can, please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes my second intent starts successfully.  I can even hardcode the textview id I want, and populate it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do that. You can't pass a view from one activity to another. What you can do, however, is to pass the previous String value of the textview and populate a new textview using it.

When you do `findViewById()` you're searching for the textview on the layout of the new activity, not the old one. The ID may or may not be the same.

Comment: Why does it work when I hard code the textview id in the next activity? Basically, instead of doing this findViewByID(R.id.primary_phone_to_call)  I want to do this findViewByID(R.id.some_variable)  This works  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("primary_phone_to_call", "id", getPackageName());
TextView text_id = (TextView) findViewById(resId);

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to do it this way?

Comment: I have 6 textboxes that I want to populate once a user has selected a contact.   Rather than have 6 different functions, I could write one and dynamically call the textviews that I want to populate.  Eventually, I'll use this same function to save the phone numbers to a sqllite database for further use.